# How to find data between two DateString format dates in mongo db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am new to manogodb and nodejs.i have  an orders collation in mongodb. Dates are stored as datestring() format  "Sat Dec 28 2019" like that i have to find data between two range dates.
my nodejs query look like this.

```
  $match: {
        "orders.kitchen": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.kitchenId),
        "orders.createdDate": {          
            $gte: (req.body.startDate),
            $lt: (req.body.endDate)
        }
    }
```

but it won't fetching the desired result.any solutions?

Comment: please show your schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the fields as proper date field in mongodb. If not, you could leverage `$dateFromString` of aggregation framework. See here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/converting-string-to-date-in-mongodb

Basically convert them to dates and then do a match query. Hope this helps

Comment: hi @Ashish its already in date format  "Sat Dec 28 2019" like this.Does the mongodb range works on specific format..or we can query every format of date?

Comment: It needs to say `date`. If you have robomongo installed, you could have a look in that